# How to get the rubycas-server login form to display?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have installed rubycas-server on my server. I have a ruby app that supports CAS on mysite.com. I would like to have the rubycas-server login page at login.mysite.com.

I have followed the instructions at http://code.google.com/p/rubycas-server/wiki/HowToConfigure and configured my config.yml file.

I have started the rubycas-server but I don't see a login form at login.mysite.com. There isn't anything on login.mysite.com. I have setup the uri_path to login.mysite.com. I thought that it would display the login form when I start the rubycas-server but it doesn't. I guess I am still missing something. What am I suppose to put on login.mysite.com in order for the login page to display? Is there suppose to be another ruby app?

Sorry, I am new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that the CAS is a single sign-on app and the CAS login page is meant to be central to all of your applications.  So a typical usage would be that you have your CAS server running on one machine, and the login will be at somedomain.com/cas.  Then you have a bunch of applications that want to authenticate, at mysite1.com, mysite2.com, etc.  If you try to browse to a CAS-protected page in one of those applications, you'll be redirected to somedomain.com/cas, where you'll sign in, and then CAS will redirect you back to the page you wanted on, say, mysite2.com.

Out of the box, you should see the login by going to the domain that rubycas-client is installed on and going to /cas.

Basically, it sounds like you're expecting the login page to be part of your application, and with CAS, it's not.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks Jacob. I just installed rubycas-client on the domain and the login form shows up now! I just didn't install the rubycas-client for the domain.